# Minecraft won't launch the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I used to play this game on my PC ,but after a complete reboot of PC it won't launch the game anymore. When it is supposed to launch it, it sends me a crash report. I have no idea how to post it over here, so here you go, the whole copy of it:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Sorry :(

Time: 29.10.16. 16.37
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_111, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 80026872 bytes (76 MB) / 148910080 bytes (142 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)

Resource Packs: 
Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
CPU: <unknown>
```

PLEASE someone try to answer to this, my knowledge of doing something on PC is complete 0.

Answer (score 0):

The two things to note in this error log are the following:

> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
>
> OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

These two lines point to an issue with the video card and/or drivers for it. Since you mentioned rebooting the PC a few times, I'm curious if you ment "*refresh*" or "*reformat*" as in when you reinstall your operating system.

**If that's the case, it's possible the computer is working fine as-is but missing the necessary video drivers to play 3D games properly.**

Unfortunately, that's the extent of the answer I can provide without knowing more about the PC. The error log itself doesn't state anything else in regards to what hardware is currently running. If you can update the question with what video card or any other information about the PC, I can point you to the correct location to download updates.

Comment: I used to have win7 and updated it to win10 ,but after  a while with lots of laggs and buggs install back to win7. Do you need me to send you my windows7 specs?

Comment: If you want to add it to the bottom of your question, I'll update my answer with links. :)

Comment: Sure, just if you can first instruct me how to do it? and what should I send you :)